# React.js Native Flexlayout

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

i am trying to make an Flexbox Layout with `React.js`.
Code:

```
 for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  articles.push(
    <View key={i} style={{height:120, flex:1}}>
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'column' , flex:1, height:120}}>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row',flex: 1}}>
          <Image style={{flex:1}}
          resizeMode={'contain'} 
          source={{uri:''}} />
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', flex: 1}}>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row' , height: 10, flex:1, bottom: 0}}>
          <Text style={{ color: 'deeppink', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>SturdiBag divided</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row' , height: 110, flex: 1, top:-30}}>
          <Text style={{ flex: 1}}>Transporttasche für bis zu 2 Tiere. Versch. Farben</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

The idea is that the picture is at the left side and right beside is the Description and the Title.
My thought was that the two Columns (l. 4&11) do this but I only get this ([Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfprC.png)) result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overcomplicating it

```
// Define the "row", now every component you put in here
// will be displayed horizontally
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1}}>
  //Now define de image container
  <View style={{ flex: 2 }}>
    <Image style={{flex:1}}
          resizeMode={'contain'} 
          source={{uri:'http://portapet.de/catalog/images/product_images/popup_images/1616_0.jpg'}} />
  </View>

  // Now define your data container
  <View style={{ flex: 8 }}>
      <Text style={{ color: 'deeppink', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>SturdiBag divided</Text>
    <Text style={{ flex: 1}}>Transporttasche für bis zu 2 Tiere. Versch. Farben</Text>
  </View>
</View>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect :)

Comment: remember, If you use "flexDirection: row"  all the elements contained on that View will be displayed horizontally but this just applies to that view. If you put another view inside, the contents of that second view will be displayed vertically again.